# JavaScript - How to hold for loop until you receive a function callback

Tags: javascript

Here is my for loop:

```
    for (var d = startDate; d <= in30DaysDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
        var loopDay = new Date(d);
        DoYourDaylyJob();
        console.log("Day:" + loopDay);
    }
```

What should i put in function `DoYourDailyJob()` to prevent the loop to go on the next day before it do it's "daily" job?

I hope i have described it well enough. Should i attach any kind of function callback at `DoYourDailyJob`, but if so how that is going to prevent the loop from proceeding until it receives response from the function ?

I'm not aware if this is possible. If it's possible can you show an example as an answer to this question ?

Comment: You will have to make a recursive function and not a `for` loop. Just make a function that keeps calling itself when its done until a certain variable has a value higher than the amount of loops. Like this `var loops = 0; function recursive(){ if( loops++ < 10 ){ console.log( loops ); recursive(); } recursive()`

Comment: Do you really need this to happen sequentially? If so, what kind of operation is this? Network requests? Usually operations like that can handle a batch. Is that not the case here?

Answer (score 9):

Just return a Promise from `DoYourDailyJob`, then its as simple as:

```
 (async function() {

 for (var d = startDate; d <= in30DaysDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    var loopDay = new Date(d);
    await DoYourDaylyJob();
    console.log("Day:" + loopDay);
 }

 })()
```

Comment: You learn something new everyday - this made me lookup the `await` and `async` keywords, which are interesting. I find this code slightly less pleasant to read because of it though.

Comment: @somethinghere i think you will change your opinion on async/await after trying out nodejs. It really improves the code when you do a lot of db requests etc and have to compose the results.

Comment: @JonasW. what do you mean by `Promise` ? Can you please add an example what `DoYourDaylyJob()` function should contain ?

Comment: @tony its up to you what `DoYourDailyJob` should do?

Answer (score 4):

Using a callback function, you replace the `for` with a recursive loop:

```
executeIteration(startDate);

function executeIteration(d) {
    if (d <= in30DaysDate)
        return;

    var loopDay = new Date(d);

    DoYourDaylyJob(function(valueFromDoYourDaylyJob) {
        executeIteration(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)));
    });
}

function DoYourDaylyJob(callback) {
    // Do your dayly job
    var valueToReturn = "foo";
    callback(valueToReturn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just refactor it so its recursive:

```
var day = 0;
var loops = 10;

function DoYourDailyJob(){

    var loopDay = new Date(d);
    console.log("Day:" + loopDay);

    if( day++ < loops ){

        DoYourDailyJob();

    }

}

DoYourDailyJob();
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't (at least without a super ugly blocking call that I can't recommend strongly enough that you avoid).

Instead, make it asynchronous.

If `DoYourDailyJob()` is something that is asynchronous, that you'll either want to make it:

- accept a callback function which is called when complete
- return a `Promise` that is resolved when complete

The `Promise` method tends to be more preferable these days:

```
function DoYourDailyJob() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do stuff
    // call resolve() when done
    // call reject() if there is an error
  });
}
```

In your `for` loop, create an array of `Dates` you want to process:

```
const dates = [];
for (var d = startDate; d <= in30DaysDate; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
  dates.push(new Date(d));
}
```

With your list of Dates, you can then either run them all in parallel:

```
Promise.all(dates.map(d => DoYourDailyJob(d))
  .then(() => console.log('all done'));
```

Or, if they need to be run one in a time (which may be the case since you don't pass in the date), you can essentially have a "queue" and a queue running function which will keep going until all of them are done:

```
const runNextDay = () => {
  if (!dates.length) {
    return Promise.resolve(); // all done
  }

  const day = dates.shift();
  return DoYourDailyJob().then(() => console.log('loop date', day))
    .then(runNextDay); // call the next day when its done
};

runNextDay()
  .then(() => console.log('all done'));
```

Answer (score -1):

All those comments are wrong, it is absolutely possible, *in some environments*.

If you have async await available, you can do it quite easily. Just make `DoYourDailyJob();` an async function (returns a promise) and do

```
for () {
   await DoYourDailyJob();
}
```

If you don't have async await available, comment that here and we can do something similar with raw promises.